# unpivoting columns into row and adding count

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a table as follows

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value1 | value1 |
| value2 | value2 | value1 |
| value2 | value1 | value2 |

I'd like to transform it as follows

| Column | Count value1 | Count value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column1 | 1 | 2 |
| Column2 | 2 | 1 |
| Column3 | 2 | 1 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
=query(ArrayFormula(split(flatten(A1:C1&"_"&A2:C), "_")), "Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col2 <>'' group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1 'Column'", 0)
```

Change rannge to suit.

[image]

Comment: I'm more found of using `␟` (symbol for unit separator; part of the [control picture Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures)) instead of a random character like underscore; it's very unlikely to be used and it actually represents what you are using it for. The formula is correct, though :)

Comment: @SamToufaili: thanks for the feedback. Glad to hear I was able to help.  Please also check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.